# Converting a Set<String> to List<Set<String>> with specific conditions using stream()

Tags: java, list, set, java-stream, hashset

I have a set let's suppose with 10 unique elements

```
Set<String> myset =new HashSet<String>();

[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
```

I wish to construct a `List<Set<String>>` such that each element of the list contains a set of size 2.

```
List<Set<String>> myList = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();

[
[a,b],
[c,d],
[e,f],
[g,h],
[i,j]
]
```

How do I implement it using `stream` in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` with `AtomicInteger` like this:

```
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
List<Set<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>(
        myset.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        s -> ai.getAndIncrement() / 2, 
                        Collectors.toSet()))
                .values());
```

Note: I used `new ArrayList` because `values()` return `Collection` and not `List` as you expect. Also if you want to got another size, you can change only 2.

response:

```
[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g, h], [i, j]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is very similar to YCF_L's solution but uses `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to handle the conversion of `Collection` to `ArrayList`.

```java
Collector<String,?,Map<Integer, Set<String>>> grpBy =
    Collectors.groupingBy(s -> ai.getAndIncrement() / 2,
                          Collectors.toSet());

return mySet.stream()
            .collect(collectingAndThen(grpBy,
                                       map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));
```

Comment: It's `collectingAndThen`, and then this could have been a comment on YCF_L's answer. :)